How to use a GPU Buffer from UE5 as input into a CUDA kernel?
I am trying to use an UE5 GPU Buffer in a CUDA kernel (from an external library).
I have looked into the only example of the Unreal Sources located in FRivermaxInputStream.cpp but couldn't reproduce their sucessful mapping, and into the CUDA Samples SimpleD3D12.cpp.
I built a minimal project where I run a lambda on the Rendering Thread that creates an RHIBuffer and tries to map it in CUDA.
Unfortunatly, the CUDA device pointer I get from cuExternalMemoryGetMappedBuffer() throws an CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE (invalid argument) on usage.
Here is a link to the main file (and minimal project) : Github Project
I am running out of ideas on what I am missing and how I can debug it.
Once we get this to work, I plan on leaving this project public as a starter point for developers in the future.
Thanks for your help.
EDIT :
Here are the key steps of my code to map the D3D12 Buffer to CUDA (I didn't want to flood the post with code, so I posted the full file on Github).
// Create the Buffer
const EBufferUsageFlags Flags = BUF_StructuredBuffer | BUF_Shared | BUF_ShaderResource | BUF_UnorderedAccess;
FRHIBuffer* const Buffer = RHICreateBuffer(Count, Flags, Stride, ResourceState, CreateInfo);
// Get the D3D12 Resource
ID3D12Resource* const NativeD3D12Resource = GetID3D12DynamicRHI()->RHIGetResource(Buffer);

// Create the D3D12 SharedHandle
HANDLE D3D12SharedHandle;
NativeD3D12Device->CreateSharedHandle(NativeD3D12Resource, nullptr, GENERIC_ALL, nullptr, &D3D12SharedHandle);

// Import the D3D12 memory in CUDA
CUDA_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_DESC Desc{};
Desc.type = CUexternalMemoryHandleType::CU_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_HANDLE_TYPE_D3D12_RESOURCE;
Desc.handle.win32.handle = D3D12SharedHandle;
Desc.size = GetID3D12DynamicRHI()->RHIGetResourceMemorySize(Buffer);
Desc.flags = CUDA_EXTERNAL_MEMORY_DEDICATED;
CUexternalMemory Handle;
FCUDAModule::CUDA().cuImportExternalMemory(&Handle, &Desc);

// Map the imported memory
CUdeviceptr Ptr;
FCUDAModule::CUDA().cuExternalMemoryGetMappedBuffer(&Ptr, CudaExternalMemoryHandle, &Desc);

// Use the CUDA ptr
FCUDAModule::CUDA().cuMemcpyHtoD(BufferCudaPtr, SomeCpuArray.GetData(), Count * Stride); // <---- CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE



having gigabytes of ue5, plus nvidia xuda, plus dirextd3d12 gpu is quite a setup for a system. we can see no code in the question. the test system is specific. maybe, just maybe you will have better luck at gamedev SO branch?

@user14063792468 Thanks for the feedback ! I added the code i find the most relevant to avoid flooding the post. Yeah I'll try the gamedev SO
